# How to set filter in the bs4 soup on the basis of the file extension?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I successfully wrote to get every file detail from [a wiki category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%A3%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D_%E0%AE%95._%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AF%E0%AF%8B%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9A%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D) by beautiful soup4 in python. The category contains `.jpg` and `.pdf` file extensions. How can i filter to get details of the pdf-files only?

**The code ;-**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rUrl  = u'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:பண்டிதர் க. அயோத்திதாசர்'

#getting all the data from above the category url
rData = requests.get(rUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rData.content, 'lxml')

#getting files name only
for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='gallerytext'):
    fileTags = item.a
    print(fileTags.text)
#getting pdfs name only
```

Its output ;-

```
Oru paisa tamilan 1.jpg
Oru paisa tamilan 2.jpg
ஒரு பூர்வ பௌத்தனின் சாட்சியம்-அயோத்திதாசரின் சொல்லாடல்.pdf
க. அயோத்திதாஸப் பண்டிதர் சிந்தனைகள்-1.pdf
க. அயோத்திதாஸப் பண்டிதர் சிந்தனைகள்-2.pdf
க. அயோத்திதாஸப் பண்டிதர் சிந்தனைகள்-4.pdf
க. அயோத்திதாஸப் பண்டிதர் சிந்தனைகள்-அரசியல்-சமூகம்.pdf
பண்டிதரின் கொடை-விகிதாச்சார உரிமை எனும் சமூகநீதிக் கொள்கை.pdf
```

How can filter pdf files only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get only the pdf links. I used `selector` to make the parser focus on those links which have this `.pdf` in the end.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rUrl  = 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:பண்டிதர் க. அயோத்திதாசர்'

rData = requests.get(rUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rData.content, 'lxml')

for item in soup.select(".gallerytext a[href$='.pdf']"):
    print(item['href'])
```

Or without using `selector`:

```
for item in soup.find_all(class_="galleryfilename"):
    if ".pdf" in item.get('href'):
        print(item['href'])
```

Comment: You could add `soup.find_all(class_="galleryfilename", href=lambda h: h and h.endswith('.pdf')` as a solution too.

Comment: Yeah, right you are. But some people do not like using lambda's that's the reason I always try to avoid that. However, If i still tried to add that, I would go like `soup.find_all("a", href=lambda h: h and ".pdf" in h)`. Thanks.